# Right scroll for an image slider

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, slider

I am attempting to make an image slider with moving buttons and carousel style. The items are added at the end or at the start to make the slider go around whichever the direction is.
The left button works as expected, but the right button either works once, either the scrolling is broken. I think it is because the parent overflow is on the right.
I made many attempts and feel I am not far from the solution, but nothing works. I also checked many, many questions SO with no help. There is no one that is 'infinite' style.

Note, that I am not interested in any packages or libraries

CSS

```
.slides-wrapper{
  width:95%;
  height:4em;
  margin-top:3em;
  margin-left:1em;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.arrow{
  z-index:1;
  cursor:pointer;
  font:larger;
  width:fit-content;
  line-height:1.5;
}

.slides{
  height:100%;
  width:94%;
  display:flex;
  overflow:hidden;
  justify-content:space-between;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.slide{
  min-width:calc(18.5% - 2px);
  margin-right:2%;
  height:100%;
  background:red;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.scroll-to-left {
   animation-duration: 1.5s;
   animation-name: scroll-to-left;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   transform: translateX(0);
}

@keyframes scroll-to-left {
   100% {
      transform: translateX(-113%);
   }
}

.scroll-to-right {
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: scroll-to-right;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    transform: translateX(-113%);
}

@keyframes scroll-to-right {
  100% {
      transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="slides-wrapper">
    <p (click)="moveSlide(false)" class="arrow left">︎◀︎</p>

    <div class="slides">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of slides; let i = index">
            <div [class.scroll-to-right]="direction=='right'" [class.scroll-to-left]="direction=='left'" class="slide">
                {{item}}
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </div>

    <p (click)="moveSlide(true);" class="arrow right">►</p>
</div>
```

TS

```
slides = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
direction = "";

moveSlide(toRight: boolean) {
  if (toRight) {
    if (this.direction) {
      this.slides.unshift(this.slides.pop());
      this.direction = "right";
    }
  } else {
    if (this.direction) {
      this.slides.push(this.slides.shift());
    }
    this.direction = "left";
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zdb63h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the behavior is different between the right (`unshift` and `pop`) and the left functions (`push` and `shift`). The left movement reloads all the slides while the right one does not.
A way to fix it can be to reload the slides with a little trick, with an `*ngIf`:

```
    <div *ngIf="visible" [class.scroll-to-right]="direction=='right'" [class.scroll-to-left]="direction=='left'" class="slide">
        {{item}}
    </div>
```

And in your component you can set the visibility to false and then back to true.

```
  this.visible = false;
  setTimeout(() => this.visible = true, 0);
```

Your stackblitz modified:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slider-with-animation?file=src/app/h-scroller.component.ts

Comment: It's a great improvement! There are small twitches when you click first left once and then to right, and it slides two elements to left after the right slides. I see your point about the reloads, I will explore that